# How do you let user input a lengthy string into a variable?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

**How do you let user input a lengthy string into a variable?**
I know this is trivial but I haven't been able to achieve it yet.

Here is what I've tried :

```
DEF VAR filter AS CHAR NO-UNDO.

UPDATE filter.
```

The value was always truncated to only a few characters. So, I've tried adding a format like so.

```
UPDATE filter FORMAT "X(318)":U.
```

Which give error

> FILL-IN filter will not fit in FRAME

This program is only used by power user, so it doesn't have a frame to make thing pretty.
The basic console is all that is needed.
318 characters would have been better than nothing, but it would still not be ideal because user may copy-paste a longer string. Note that user wouldn't not paste any string that exceed 32000 characters.

Here is what the user input would looks like.

`value1,value2,value3,value4,value5,value6,value7,value8,value9,value10,value11`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I occasionally use something along these lines:

```
/* editlong.p
 *
 */

define variable longText as character no-undo format "x(1000)"
  view-as fill-in size 40 by 1
  label "Long Text"
.

update longText "...".
```

The format "x(1000)" could just as easily be format "x(32000)". But whatever it is, it will be the hard limit on what someone can enter.

You could also do multi-line entry like this:

```
define variable longText as character no-undo format "x(1000)"
  view-as editor inner-chars 30 inner-lines 5
  large no-word-wrap
  label "Long Text"
.

update longText "...".
```